# Having some trouble with my php syntax in current category

Tags: php, syntax, categories

Hey guys I am trying to pull a list based on my current category selected. I am getting a syntax error. I think I have the right idea but my execution is that of a noob.

here is what i am trying to do.

```
<?php $current_category = '($detailRecord['category'])'; ?>

<?php

// load list records from 'blog_stories'
list($blog_storiesRecords, $blog_storiesMetaData) = getRecords(array(
'tableName'   => 'blog_stories',
'limit'       => '5',
'loadUploads' => false,
'allowSearch' => false,
'where' => "category = '$current_category'",
 ));

 ?>
```

it is giving me this error.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on line 19

Comment: what is on line 19? also <?php $current_category = '($detailRecord['category'])'; ?> I am sure it should be
<?php $current_category = $detailRecord['category']; ?>

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the quotes here:

```
<?php $current_category = $detailRecord['category']; ?>
```

Comment: You *can* have a comma after the last element of an array.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong

```
$current_category = '($detailRecord['category'])'; ?>
                    ^ opening quote ^ closing quote followed by a T_STRING
```

This is correct

```
$current_category = $detailRecord['category'];
```